# Empty file with my automatic script to do back-up of my data base (manually it's ok)

Tags: mysql, cron, is-empty, mysql-backup

I try to save my database from my wordpress on a EC2 instance in AWS.
Manually it's ok if i do :

```
mysqldump -u root -p*mypassword* bitnami_wordpress > bdd.sql</i>
```

But if i do this script (test.sh) :

```
#!/bin/bash

################################################################
##
##   MySQL Database Backup Script
##   Written By: Rahul Kumar
##   URL: https://tecadmin.net/bash-script-mysql-database-backup/
##   Last Update: Jan 05, 2019
##
################################################################

export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
TODAY=`date +"%d%b%Y"`

################################################################
################## Update below values  ########################

DB_BACKUP_PATH='/home/bitnami/db_backup/'
MYSQL_USER='root'
MYSQL_PASSWORD='VTj28yRtKJRn'
DATABASE_NAME='bitnami_wordpress'
BACKUP_RETAIN_DAYS=2   ## Number of days to keep local backup copy

#################################################################

mkdir -p ${DB_BACKUP_PATH}/${TODAY}
echo "Backup started for database - ${DATABASE_NAME}"


mysqldump \
   -u ${MYSQL_USER} \
   -p${MYSQL_PASSWORD} \
   ${DATABASE_NAME} > ${DB_BACKUP_PATH}/${TODAY}        /${DATABASE_NAME}-${TODAY}.sql

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Database backup successfully completed"
else
  echo "Error found during backup"
  exit 1
fi


##### Remove backups older than {BACKUP_RETAIN_DAYS} days  #####

DBDELDATE=`date +"%d%b%Y" --date="${BACKUP_RETAIN_DAYS} days ago"`

if [ ! -z ${DB_BACKUP_PATH} ]; then
      cd ${DB_BACKUP_PATH}
      if [ ! -z ${DBDELDATE} ] && [ -d ${DBDELDATE} ]; then
            rm -rf ${DBDELDATE}
      fi
fi

### End of script ####
```

And in my crontab :

```
<i>*/1 * * * * /home/bitnami/scripts/mysql/test.sh</i>
```

Why I receive a empty file ?

The file is in 777.
The server is on AWS with ec2.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: you should change your MySQL username/password directly on the server....

Comment: Also i believe this question is better suited for https://serverfault.com, here it is in the gray area  of [offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as this is more or less server configuration..